# Placeholder as props not working in Vue form

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a Form Answer component:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2">
    <!-- <p class="font-semibold">{{ ansLabel }}</p> -->
    <div
      class="flex items-center justify-center gap-5 rounded-3xl border-2 border-gray-300 p-5 shadow-md"
    >
      <textarea class="w-[700px]" :placeholder="ansPlaceholder"> </textarea>
      <input type="checkbox" name="isTrue" id="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const props = defineProps({
  ansPlaceholder: {
    type: String,
    default: 'default'
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

and then how i use it:

```
<template>
  <div
    name="form container"
    class="mx-2 flex w-[70%] flex-col items-center rounded-3xl border-2 border-black p-3"
  >
    <div
      name="question"
      class="flex w-fit flex-col items-center justify-center gap-3 border-2 border-blue-500 p-3"
    >
      <p class="font-semibold">Question</p>
      <textarea placeholder="Add a question"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div name="answers" class="flex w-fit flex-col gap-5 border-2 border-green-500 p-3">
      <FormAnswer ansPlaceholder="Answer A"></FormAnswer>
      <FormAnswer ansPlaceholder="Answer B"></FormAnswer>
      <FormAnswer ansPlaceholder="Answer C"></FormAnswer>
      <FormAnswer ansPlaceholder="Answer D"></FormAnswer>
      <FormAnswer ansPlaceholder="Answer E"></FormAnswer>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import FormAnswer from '../AdminDashboardCmp/FormAnswer.vue'
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

but i have a problem with a placeholder as a prop. So when the page render, there are no placeholders for textare. If a enter a text, and then i delete it, then the placeholder occurs. How to make placeholder render with the form, not after i enter something and then delete it?

I tried adding reactive data and watcher, but it didnt work.

Comment: You seem to have a space between the opening and closing tag of your textarea

Comment: thanks sir! your are a genis for spotting that detail! thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a space between the opening and closing tag of your textarea.

`<textarea>` is one of the few tags to take into accounts whitespace. Removing it will effectively make it empty-valued, which is when the placeholder is shown.